# Magento 1.9.4 : Prevent the css and js of the skin folder to load in a cms page

Tags: magento-1.9, cms

I want to style its elements by myself (for example, I want to style the header different from the rest of the website) but Magento loads the styles from the skin folder. How can I prevent Magento from loading styles in a page?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the `Layout Update XML` section on the **Design** **tab** of the **CMS page** you want to remove it from, and then **clear the Magento cache**.

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>directory/filename.css</name></action>
</reference>
```

You can then create your own custom stylesheet in your skin directory and add it to only this page using `method="addItem"` instead.